# Burn 24/96 flac files to play on standalone player

Tags: ubuntu, audio, dvd, burning, flac

I have vinyl record rip in 24/96 flac format. Each track is almost 200 MB big, so the album won't fit on CD.

How to burn these files on a DVD to play with the same quality on standalone DVD player?

My player supports SACD, DVD Audio and DVD video as well. My OS is Ubuntu Lucid (preferred), but I have also WinXp with Nero installed.

BTW, is there any difference between DVD+ and DVD- for audio?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a DVD-Audio disc using [DVD audio tools](http://dvd-audio.sourceforge.net/). There's a howto on the website with step-by-step instructions. I've made DVDs from 24/96 audio that I bought from HDTracks and they play on my standalone DVD player (which is DVD-Audio capable)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks very promising, however I don't know how to create `sort.txt`. The patched files seems to be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you'd create DVD Audio or SACD discs from those; hopefully someone else will chime in with specifics in another answer.

You'd have to downgrade the audio to standard 16/44.1 stereo to burn them as a standard audio CD -- in which case the album would fit on a standard CD.

Frankly, I'd burn the data files to a standard (or better, archival quality) data DVD, using some form of error correction like that provided by *par2* or *dvdisaster* (Ubuntu packages).  You can play them back with an HTPC, and you won't need to do any reencoding of the files.  This would be a good backup to have even if you did make Audio DVDs or SACDs from them, so keep it in mind.